# How can I email my lookback video to non Facebook users?

Tags: facebook

I'd like to email my [Facebook lookback video](https://www.facebook.com/lookback) to someone who does not have a Facebook account.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you share it as public (it has to be public for non-Facebook users to be able to see it) on your timeline you can share the link to it with anyone. Right click on the time stamp and copy the link.

[image: FB Lookback]